# "Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS and CURLPROTO_HTTP" but it works?

Tags: php, curl, notice

Hi on our dev environment we have show all errors, warnings and notices. I'm getting this:

Notice: Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS - assumed 'CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS' in **C:\notion\implementation\development\asterix\library\ExternalLibs\panda.php**  on line **69**

**Notice**: Use of undefined constant CURLPROTO_HTTP - assumed 'CURLPROTO_HTTP' in **C:\notion\implementation\development\asterix\library\ExternalLibs\panda.php** on line **69**

The code on line 69:

```
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_HTTP);
```

But the CURL code works, it goes off to the other server and retrieves whats necessary. What do these notices mean?

Thanks very much.

Comment: See also [my attempt at a canonical answer for causes of this error message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941169/what-does-the-php-error-message-notice-use-of-undefined-constant-mean/8025500#8025500).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seemed to be a bug in PHP 5.2.9: [#48390](http://bugs.php.net/48390)

> According to the documentation, the option "CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS" is available as of cURL 7.19.4, but PHP is throwing a notice: "Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS - assumed 'CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS'"
>
> Also all the "CURLPROTO_*" constants are not available:
>
> Use of undefined constant CURLPROTO_HTTPS - assumed 'CURLPROTO_HTTPS'

I don't know what this setting does exactly, but I would assume in your case, the setting is not applied at all, because curl can't interpret the string "CURLPROTO_HTTP". If it works either way, it may be safer to comment it out, because with the next upgrade, the constants are likely to be there.

Comment: Thanks Pekka, and I don't know why I didn't turn up that bug report myself while searching. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

This issue can occur either curl extension is not enabled or available.

Try to install curl extension from  [how to download curl on ubuntu][1]

I faced same issue when I was calling a script with php-cli  but the extension was not enabled for cli mode.