# Use of undefined constant ADMIN - assumed 'ADMIN'

Tags: php, constants

I'm getting the error `Use of undefined constant NORMAL - assumed 'NORMAL'` when running my code, I can't find anything wrong with th code

```
var $type;

    const NORMAL=1;
    const ADMIN=2;

    public function getTypeOptions(){
        return array(
            self::NORMAL=>'Normal',
            self::ADMIN=>'Administrator',
        );
    }

    public function getTypeText(){

        $options[NORMAL];
        $options[ADMIN];

        $options=$this->getTypeOptions();
        return $options;
    }

    public function getTypeByText($type){
        $options = $this->getTypeText();
        if($type == 1){
            return $options[1];
        }else if($type == 2){
            return $options[2];
        }
    }
```

I get this everytime I call the getTypeByText method the value of type = 2

Comment: See also [my attempt at a canonical answer for causes of this error message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941169/what-does-the-php-error-message-notice-use-of-undefined-constant-mean/8025500#8025500).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your referencing a global constant, you need to reference a local constant.

```
$options[self::NORMAL];
$options[self::ADMIN];
```

should work

Just a note, looking at the way your class::method is built, you don't actually need the above, the below will work just fine.

```
public function getTypeText()
{
    return $this->getTypeOptions();
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that make `getTypeText()` completely redundant since they're just synonyms (which by their method names they *shouldn't* be)?

Comment: regardless of my change, there still pointless as the method was already redundant.