# Why const is undefined in static function?

Tags: php, static, constants

Why the `name` constant is not recognised in the static function `f2()` ?

```
class Foo {
    protected static function f1($s) {
        echo "doing $s";
    }
}
class Bar extends Foo {
    const name = 'leo';
    public static function f2() {
        Foo::f1(name);
    }
}
$bar = new Bar();
$bar->f2();
```

I get the following error:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant name - assumed 'name' in ...
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: See also [my attempt at a canonical answer for causes of this error message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941169/what-does-the-php-error-message-notice-use-of-undefined-constant-mean/8025500#8025500).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Quite simple, the `name` constant is undefined.  What you defined is a [class constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php).  You can access it through either:

```
Bar::name
```

or from within the `Bar` class or any of its descendants

```
self::name
```

or from within the `Bar` class or any of its descendants with 5.3+ only:

```
static::name
```

So, change the call to:

```
public static function f2() {
    Foo::f1(self::name);
}
```

And that should do it for you...

Oh, and one other note.  Typically, the naming convention is that constants should be all uppercase.  So it should be `const NAME = 'leo';`, and referenced using `self::NAME`.  You don't *have* to do it that way, but I do think it helps readability...

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Many of the answers to similar questions were difficult for me to understand when to use static vs. self with class constants. This made it very clear.