# PHP Undefined Constant PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN

Tags: php, constants, undefined, rounding

I have some PHP code in a project I'm working on that uses PHP's round function. On my localhost, I don't include any quotes around my mode argument, stating it as just PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN. However, when pushing to my server I get the error message:

```
Use of undefined constant PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN - assumed 'PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN'
Warning (2): Wrong parameter count for round() [APP/views/helpers/time_left.php, line 14]
```

Now, when I add the single quotes to the mode argument, the first error goes away, however the "wrong parameter count" remains. I'm calling the function as follows:

```
$days = round(($difference/$day), 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
```

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: See also [my attempt at a canonical answer for causes of this error message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941169/what-does-the-php-error-message-notice-use-of-undefined-constant-mean/8025500#8025500).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [rounding mode](http://php.net/manual/function.round.php) was added in PHP 5.3. Make sure you're running at least that version.

You can see which version you're running by placing the following in a PHP file:

```
var_dump(phpversion());
```

Answer (score 11):

The mode argument was only [added in PHP 5.3.0.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) If you're running an earlier version of PHP, then the mode option constants (PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN, PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN, and PHP_ROUND_HALF_ODD) won't be defined

**EDIT**

You can't use the mode argument for round() prior to 5.3.0, but you can achieve the equivalent by combining functions:

```
round(floor($value * 100) / 100,2); //  to round down to 2dp
round(floor($value * 1000) / 1000,3); //  to round down to 3dp
round(ceil($value * 100) / 100,2); //  to round up to 2dp
```

Comment: Is there a way to still use the mode argument? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. Question: Why you use 100?.  Using 10 instead 100 also works.

Comment: Use 100 when it's 2dp, 1000 for 3dp, 100000 for 5dp, etc.... count the number of zeroes

Answer (score 5):

`PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN` requires PHP 5.3.0 as seen here: http://php.net/manual/en/math.constants.php

You're probably on a lower PHP version.

Answer (score 3):

round() defaults to using PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP but you can only change it in PHP >= 5.3.0

To emulate PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN I think you can subtract (1/10^(precision+1))*5 from the number before rounding.

to put it simply;

```
<?php
  $number=20.005;
  $precision=2;
  echo round($number,$precision);                         //20.01
  echo round($number-(1/10^($precision+1))*5,$precision); //20.00
  echo round($number-0.005,2);                            //20.00
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

What version of PHP is running on your server?  According to [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) only PHP 5.3 or greater supports the PHP_ROUND constants.

Answer (score 2):

Is `PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN`supported by your version?

[According to the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) mode wasnt introduced till 5.3

```
5.3.0    The mode parameter was introduced.
```

You can use [`floor`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) instead (or [`ceil`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) if you want to go the other way)

Answer (score 0):

$mode was added on PHP 5.3

check php's version with:

```
php -v
```

edit:
or use php's phpinfo() procedure

cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
$qty = 15;
$size = 6;
$box= round(($qty)/($size), 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_ODD);
$picecs = ($qty)%($size);
echo 'BOX=='.$box. 'PICECS==='.$picecs;
```