# What is the meaning of the "Use of undefined constant" notice in PHP?

Tags: php, html, forms

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant username - assumed 'username' in
/home/content/04/7195304/html/header.php on line 54
```

I get this when writing things like `$_COOKIE[username]` or `$_POST[username]`.

**Edit**

So I've been playing around with the code, putting quotes in my POST, COOKIE, and GET's.. I still get the same thing!

Comment: Technically, it is not an error. But you should fix it anyway!

Comment: Is this still a problem? If so, you should add the code of the line which is mentioned in the error message (and maybe some lines around it). (If it is solved, you should instead accept the answer which most helped, or add an own answer instead.)

Comment: See also [my attempt at a canonical answer for causes of this error message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941169/what-does-the-php-error-message-notice-use-of-undefined-constant-mean/8025500#8025500).

Answer (score 6):

It means you likely forgot  a $ in front of your variable name.

**Edit**
You need to encapsulate your call in qoutes.  I.e.

```
$_COOKIE["username"]
```

or

```
$_POST["username"]
```

Comment: I did that. Still does the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

It probably means you forgot to put a `$` in front of your `username` variable, so it's treating it like a constant instead of a variable.

You should post the code from that line for better help.

Comment: Ah. The code helps. You didn't put quotes around your array keys. Try `$_COOKIE['username']`

Comment: Can you copy line 52 - 56 of the actual file?

Comment: Hm. Well, actually, I've been playing around with the code, so that no longer matters. I keep getting errors like 'Notice: Undefined index: register in /home/content/04/7195304/html/index.php on line 19'.. Line 19 is if ($_POST['register']) {

Comment: Well, a notice isn't an error. If I say `echo $_POST['foo']` and I don't have that in my array, it would give that notice. If you want to avoid it, you probably want to do `if(isset($_POST['register'])) {`

Answer (score 1):

You might as well try $_COOKIE['username'] or $_POST['username'], to access the associative arrays with a string.

Sorry, overlooked comment with same advice.