# PHP Notice: Use of undefined constant type

Tags: php

I'm doing something wrong and I can't figure out what to do about it (how to fix it)

code:

```
var_dump($each->promotion-type);
```

returns:

```
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant type - assumed 'type' in newfile.php on line 19
```

I can't change that variable name as that how I get from my vendor, any ideas how I can access that promotion-type variable? (syntax wise)

Comment: You get an *object* like that from your vendor? Where is that data coming from? Isn't it possible to use an array instead?

Comment: @deceze: For all you know it might have been extracted from JSON, and dashes are perfectly fine in JSON object keys...

Comment: @Bolt Exactly, in which case decoding it to an array would be more appropriate.

Comment: @deceze: data comes in XML, but looks like BoltClock answer my question, so thanks to all :)

Comment: See also [my attempt at a canonical answer for this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941169/what-does-the-php-error-message-notice-use-of-undefined-constant-mean/8025500#8025500)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's spitting that notice because the expression is being interpreted as variable `$each->promotion` minus constant `type`.

To access a property with the dash in its name, use curly braces and quotes:

```
var_dump($each->{'promotion-type'});
```