# PHP sessions, undefined constant

Tags: php

```
<?php 

session_start(); 


if (!isset($_SESSION[auth])) {

    header('Location: login.php');
}

else {

    $auth = $_SESSION[auth];
}

if ($auth == 1) {

    echo "User access has been granted!";
}

else {

    header('Location: login.php');
}

?>
```

I am getting: Notice: Use of undefined constant auth - assumed 'auth'. I don't understand this error, I am checking to make sure that $_SESSION[auth] is set. Cannot find good answers on web.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the PHP error message "Notice: Use of undefined constant" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941169/what-does-the-php-error-message-notice-use-of-undefined-constant-mean)

Answer (score 2):

Need single quotes around auth

```
$_SESSION['auth']
```

Comment: *slaps hand against forehead*

Answer (score 1):

Quote it to - `$auth = $_SESSION['auth'];` instead of `$auth = $_SESSION[auth];`