# Use of undefined constant id - assumed 'id'

Tags: php, html-table

I have code but get this error:

> Use of undefined constant id - assumed 'id'

```
elseif(isset($_GET['aksi']) && $_GET['aksi']=='edit'){
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    echo"<br>
        <form method=POST action='?aksi=update_data'>
            <table>
                <tr><td>Id</td><td><input type=text name='id' value='".$db->bacaData(id,$id)."'></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Nama</td><td><input type=text name='nama' value='".$db->bacaData(nama,$id)."'></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Email</td><td><input type=text name='email' value='".$db->bacaData(email,$id)."'></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Pesan</td><td><input type=text name='pesan' value='".$db->bacaData(pesan,$id)."'></td></tr>
                <tr><td></td><td><input type=submit value='simpan'></td></tr>
            </table>
        <input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$db->bacaData(id,$id)."'>
        </form>
    ";

}
```

error undefined constant id code below:

```
<tr><td>Id</td><td><input type=text name='id' value='".$db->bacaData(id,$id)."'></td></tr>
```

Can you help me solve this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the PHP error message "Notice: Use of undefined constant" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941169/what-does-the-php-error-message-notice-use-of-undefined-constant-mean)

Answer (score 13):

**Replace**

```
<input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$db->bacaData(id,$id)."'>
```

**with**

```
<input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$db->bacaData('id',$id)."'>
                              ------------------------^^^^---
```

you are using `id` and php will count it as constant so wrap it inside single quote.

Even you have same error for other declaration too wrap first argument inside of `''`.

**Correct Code**

```
elseif(isset($_GET['aksi']) && $_GET['aksi']=='edit')
{
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    echo"<br>
        <form method=POST action='?aksi=update_data'>
            <table>
                <tr><td>Id</td><td><input type=text name='id' value='".$db->bacaData('id',$id)."'></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Nama</td><td><input type=text name='nama' value='".$db->bacaData('nama',$id)."'></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Email</td><td><input type=text name='email' value='".$db->bacaData('email',$id)."'></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Pesan</td><td><input type=text name='pesan' value='".$db->bacaData('pesan',$id)."'></td></tr>
                <tr><td></td><td><input type=submit value='simpan'></td></tr>
            </table>
        <input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$db->bacaData('id',$id)."'>
        </form>
    ";
}
```