# Use of undefined constant STDIN - assumed 'STDIN'

Tags: php

```
<?php
echo "Hello there. So I hear you're learning to be a PHP programmer!\n";
echo "Why don't you type in your name for me:\n";
$name = trim(fgets(STDIN));
echo "\nThanks, " . $name . ", it's really nice to meet you.\n\n";
?>
```

a am using php version 5.5.19
xampp

Comment: What is `STDIN`? a string, a constant?

Comment: [What does the PHP error message “Notice: Use of undefined constant” mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941169/what-does-the-php-error-message-notice-use-of-undefined-constant-mean)

Comment: What is your question??

Comment: Are you running that in a web mode? [STDIN](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php) is a CLI specific constant.

Comment: I think u should use define('STDIN',fopen("php://stdin","r"));
in the at top of the php file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

echo "Hello there. So I hear you're learning to be a PHP programmer!\n";

echo "Why don't you type in your name for me:\n";

$stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');

$name=trim(fgets($stdin));

echo "\nThanks, " . $name . ", it's really nice to meet you.\n\n";

fclose($file);

?>
```

Comment: thanks                                                                                                                                                  this code work fine in cmd.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are running from command line interface (CLI):

Define a `STDIN` constant at the top of your file:

```
define('STDIN', fopen('php://stdin', 'r'));
```

Or just replace `STDIN` constant with:

```
$name = trim(fgets(fopen('php://stdin', 'r')));
```