# ErrorException Use of undefined constant datepickerTitle - assumed 'datepickerTitle' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

Tags: php, laravel

i have uploaded my file into laravel server/environment after this i get multiple error i'll try to resolve 10 to 15 times but it will not work

[image]

```
    <div class="datepicker"
         ng-class="{
            'am': timeframe == 'am',
            'pm': timeframe == 'pm',
            'compact': compact
        }">
        <div class="datepicker-header">
            <div class="datepicker-title" ng-if="datepicker_title">{{ datepickerTitle }}</div>
            <div class="datepicker-subheader">{{ customMessage }} {{ selectedDay }} {{ monthNames[localdate.getMonth()] }} {{ localdate.getDate() }}, {{ localdate.getFullYear() }}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="datepicker-calendar">
            <div class="calendar-header">
                <div class="goback" ng-click="moveBack()" ng-if="pickdate">
                    <svg width="30" height="30">
                        <path fill="none" stroke="#23527c" stfroke-width="3" d="M19,6 l-9,9 l9,9"/>
                    </svg>
                </div>
                <div class="current-month-container">{{ currentViewDate.getFullYear() }} {{ currentMonthName() }}</div>
                <div class="goforward" ng-click="moveForward()" ng-if="pickdate">
                    <svg width="30" height="30">
                        <path fill="none" stroke="#23527c" stroke-width="3" d="M11,6 l9,9 l-9,9" />
                    </svg>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the PHP error message "Notice: Use of undefined constant" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941169/what-does-the-php-error-message-notice-use-of-undefined-constant-mean)

Comment: Have you tried using a PHP identifier to reference the variable? Give it a go... ;-) `$datepickerTitle`

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing angular and blade, which is totally fine... but you need to keep that stuff straight.

`{{ $bladeVar }}` and `@{{ ngVar }}`

... you need the @ sign if you're inside angular and you need the $ sign if you're in blade/php.

In this particular parsing error situation, blade/php is asking for a dollar sign.

Comment: i'll try but still it's not working . pls help me to get out this problem