# How to import data from another file? laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get the data from the below file. I want to know is this possible to achieve? and how we to import it in another file? Purpose of this, is for my unit testing.

I tried the below code but it returns an error.

```
dd(userData);
```

> ErrorException: Use of undefined constant userData - assumed 'userData'

---

**userData.php**

```
<?php

return [
    [
        'name' => 'Perla',
        'age' => 13,
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Felepe',
        'age' => 23,
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Timoteo',
        'age' => 50,
    ]
]
```

Comment: you can put the file in the config folder and call it with `config('userData')`

Comment: @N69S i want to put it under the `tests` folder, since it will be use for testing.

Comment: then what prevents you from adding that array into a method of the setup class like `getSampleUsers()` or something like that, why does it have to be in a seperate file ?

Comment: @N69S i think its messy. and thought to separate so, other test file can use it, just in case

Comment: yeah, put it in the setup class, wich is accessible by all tests.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the PHP error message "Notice: Use of undefined constant" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941169/what-does-the-php-error-message-notice-use-of-undefined-constant-mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import it by following according to your userData.php

```
$userData = include('test/data/userData.php');
```

Comment: if its under the `tests\data` folder? how to include sir?

Comment: where is the file that includes userData?

Comment: its under `tests\Unit\UserTest.php`

Comment: can you try the new version of answer.

Comment: I have changed it.